# How to set an anchor tag in Customer/controllers/AccountController.php in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, html

[image]

I have set anchor tag for that, but anchor tag is not working.

How to set an anchor tag? Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: can you add your code what did you write for setup anchor tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some javascript issue thats why your link is not set

Comment: Is that possible?.

Comment: Yes, I have found some custom javascript code. I commented that code and check. It's working. Thank you so much for your idea.